# prime factors of a radical number

Tags: r, primes, prime-factoring

I have managed to find the prime factors of a number with the following code:

```
   library(gmp)
   typ <- match_exams_device()
   #--------------------------------------------------------
   pipa <- as.numeric(factorize(25))
   pipa
```

But, what I am looking for is to represent the simplified radical number. For example

[image]

be expressed as

[image]

In this case, it would be enough to obtain the factors that remain outside the radical, and then multiply them. The same procedure would be applied for the factors that give as a result the number that remains inside the radical

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: factor the number inside the radical into distinct prime powers (p1^e1) * (p2^e2 )* ... . Now if e_i is even then p_i ^ (e_i / 2) is in the product outside the radical. If e_i is odd then p_i ^ ((e_i - 1) / 2) is in the product outside the radical and p_i is in the product insider the radical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return an expression as the output:

```
radical_simplify <- function(x, r) {
  fac <- as.integer(gmp::factorize(x))
  unq <- unique(fac)
  n <- tabulate(match(fac, unq))
  rad <- prod(unq^(n %% r))
  if (rad == 1L) {
    parse(text = prod(unq^(n %/% r)))
  } else {
    mult <- prod(unq^(n %/% r))
    if (r == 2L) {
      if (mult == 1L) {
        parse(text = paste0("sqrt(", rad, ")"))
      } else {
        parse(text = paste0(mult, "*sqrt(", rad, ")"))
      }
    } else {
      if (mult == 1L) {
        parse(text = paste0("", rad, "^(1/", r, ")"))
      } else {
        parse(text = paste0(mult, "*", rad, "^(1/", r, ")"))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
radical_simplify(12L, 2L)
#> expression(2*sqrt(3))
radical_simplify(120L, 3L)
#> expression(2*15^(1/3))
identical(9375^(1/5), eval(radical_simplify(9375, 5)))
#> [1] TRUE
```

**UPDATE**

To explain the function, I'll step through the first two examples given.

1. `sqrt(12)`: The factors from `fac <- gmp::factorize(12)` are 2, 2, 3. The unique factors from `unq <- unique(fac)` are 2 and 3. `n <- tabulate(match(fac, unq))` returns the numbers of times each of the unique factors occur, which are 2 and 1. With `r = 2`, we are taking the second (square) root, so every 2 times the unique factors occur (given by the quotient `n %/% r = c(2, 1) %/% 2 = c(1, 0)`), we can pull it out of the radical. Multiply all the factors that get pulled out of the radical to get the outside number: `mult <- prod(unq^(n %/% r)) = 2^1*3^0 = 2`. Similarly, the remainder operation gives the count of each unique factor that remains inside the radical: `n %% r = c(2, 1) %% 2 = c(0, 1)`. Multiply all the factors that remain inside the radical to get the inside number: `rad <- prod(unq^(n %% r)) = 2^0*3^1 = 3`.
2. `120^(1/3)`: The factors from `fac <- gmp::factorize(120)` are 2, 2, 2, 3, 5. The unique factors from `unq <- unique(fac)` are 2, 3, 5. `n <- tabulate(match(fac, unq))` returns the numbers of times each of the unique factors occur, which are 3, 1, and 1. With `r = 3`, we are taking the third (cube) root, so every 3 times the unique factors occur (given by the quotient `n %/% r = c(3, 1, 1) %/% 3 = c(1, 0, 0)`), we can pull it out of the radical. Multiply all the factors that get pulled out of the radical to get the outside number: `mult <- prod(unq^(n %/% r)) = 2^1*3^0*5^0 = 2`. Similarly, the remainder operation gives the count of each unique factor that remains inside the radical: `n %% r = c(3, 1, 1) %% 3 = c(0, 1, 1)`. Multiply all the factors that remain inside the radical to get the inside number: `rad <- prod(unq^(n %% r)) = 2^0*3^1*5^1 = 15`.

The `if` statements that make up remainder of the code are to cleanly format the expression that gets returned.

Comment: Hello. I don't understand how it works

Comment: I added an update that walks through the first two examples in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution

```
f <- function(n, r) {
  k <- 2
  v <- c()
  while (n >= k) {
    if (!(n %% k)) {
      v <- c(v, k)
      n <- n / k
    } else {
      k <- k + 1
    }
  }
  d <- table(v)
  z <- as.integer(names(d))
  if (all(d %% r == 0)) {
    return(as.expression(prod(z^(d %/% r))))
  }
  if (all(d %/% r == 0)) {
    return(str2lang(sprintf("%s^(1/%s)", prod(z^(d %% r)), r)))
  }
  str2lang(sprintf("%s*%s^(1/%s)", prod(z^(d %/% r)), prod(z^(d %% r)), r))
}
```

and we can see

```
> f(1024, 4)
4 * 4^(1/4)

> f(24, 2)
2 * 6^(1/2)

> f(24, 3)
2 * 3^(1/3)

> f(23, 2)
23^(1/2)
```

Comment: How can I convert 23^(1/2) to Latex math script?

Comment: @ElDiariodeAlvaretto Do you mean the string `"$\sqrt(23)$"` or `"$23^{\frac{1}{2}}$"`?

Comment: `"$\sqrt(23)$"` I don't know how to include it in an Rmarkdown chunk.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have created something functional. The following code is the result of merging and organizing some ideas found on the web. Excuse the inelegance in the code:

```
   library(exams)
   library(gmp)
   library(dplyr)
   library(plyr)

   typ <- match_exams_device()
   #--------------------------------------------------------
   pipadf <- count(as.numeric(factorize(10)))
   pipadf <- pipadf[order(pipadf$freq), ]
   pipadf
   pipa <- as.numeric(factorize(10))
   pipa
   kuantos <- length(pipa)
   kuantos <- kuantos + 1
   kuantos
   pases <- length(pipadf$freq)
   pases
   x <- 1
   nuevovektor <- vector()

   while(x <= pases){
   unovek <- rep(pipadf[x,1],pipadf[x,2])
   nuevovektor <- c(nuevovektor,unovek)
   x <- x+1
   }

   nuevovektor <- c(nuevovektor,1)
   nuevovektor

   i <- 1
   fderaiz <- vector()
   dderaiz <- vector()

   while(i <= kuantos-1){
   if(nuevovektor[i]==nuevovektor[i+1]){
   x <- nuevovektor[i]
   fderaiz <- c(fderaiz, x)
   i <- i+2
   }else {
    x <- nuevovektor[i]
    dderaiz <- c(dderaiz, x)
    i <- i+1
   }
   }
 
   fderaiz
   dderaiz

   sinrad <- prod(fderaiz)
   sinrad

   conrad <- prod(dderaiz)
   conrad
```